# Lookup nested fields in mongodb array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

## Schema

```js
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60e09c90402cbd625d7a8162"),
        "title" : "...",
        "author" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d")),
        "posts" : [ ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60e09c97402cbd625d7a8163"),
        "title" : "...",
        "author" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d")),
        "posts" : [ ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60e09d06402cbd625d7a8164"),
        "title" : "...",
        "author" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d")),
        "posts" : [ ]
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60e09d07402cbd625d7a8165"),
        "title" : "...",
        "author" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d")),
        "posts" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60e12300e931cd14c03ecd89"),
                "title" : "...",
                "author" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d"))
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("60e12305e931cd14c03ecd8a"),
                "title" : "...",
                "author" : DBRef("users", ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d"))
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Each document will have a `title`, `author` and `posts` attribute. `author` attribute is a [$ref](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/)  and `posts` attribute is an array of documents. Each document of `posts` will also have `title, author`.

### What i want

I want to get all documents with authors and it's `posts`(with author).

### Query

```js
db.blogs.aggregate([
  { $project: {title:1,author:1,"posts.title":1,"posts._id":1,"posts.author":1} },
  { "$lookup": { "from": "users", "localField": "author.$id", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "author" } },
  { "$lookup": { "from": "users", "localField": "posts.author.$id", "foreignField": "_id", "as": "posts.author" } }
])
```

### Response

```js
[
  {
    "_id": '..',
    "title": "..",
    "author": [
      {
        // author details
      }
    ],
    "posts": {
      "author": []
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": '..',
    "title": "...",
    "author": [
      {
        // author details
      }
    ],
    "posts": {
      "author": []
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": '..',
    "title": "..",
    "author": [
      {
        // author details
      }
    ],
    "posts": {
      "author": []
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ...,
    "title": "2 Type SR Blog, my first blog.",
    "author": [
      {
        // author details
      }
    ],
    "posts": {
      "author": [
        {
        // author details
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

### Users Collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60ce9146f41866120ee70c0d"),
    "name" : "Rahul kumar",
    "status" : "A Fake Developer",
    "__v" : 0,
    "pic" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/bdevg/image/upload/v1604287418/pic_xexz8o.jpg"
}
```

### Problem

You can see the last document, which only has `posts` attribute. It should also contain `title` attribute.

Comment: your example aggregation sample shows $lookup to a collection called 'users'.  I don't see examples of these documents in your post.

Comment: You are performing 2 $lookups and using output field names that are overwriting another field.  My recommendation is to always use a new field name and not pave over the existing field names.  Also, the second $lookup is pulling data from the collection 'users' which may or may not have a title attribute - you have not provided any examples of documents in the users collection, but I suspect the users collection does not have a field called 'title' and thus it will never have one in the output.

Comment: @barrypicker I have added users collection Now.

Comment: Author of `posts` array's document can be different than blogs author. So, i want author of post to be included as `posts.author`.

Comment: You can see, in the second lookup `"as": "posts.author" `.

Comment: don't pass `.$id` in `localField`, try `author` and `posts.author`.

Comment: @turivishal after removeing `$id` it's not returning `author` field.

Comment: I think `"as": "posts.author"` is over writing the `posts[idx]` it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `posts` array
- `$lookup` with `users` collection and pass `posts.author` as localField
- `$unwind` to deconstruct `author` array
- `$group` by `_id` and reconstruct the `posts` array and get first value for other required fields
- `$lookup` with `users` and pass `author` as localField
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the `author` array

```
db.blogs.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$posts.author",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "posts.author",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "posts.author"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$posts.author",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      title: { $first: "$title" },
      posts: { $push: "$posts" },
      author: { $first: "$author" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "author",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "author"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$author",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lVLhs1BpECe)